# Most efficient way of using onListItemClick?

Tags: android

I was working with the source code found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rs9mSnWDlZo

Basically, he made a list adapter which works with the SherlockActionBar. He didn't include the method onListItemClick in the code, which I wanted to use to make each list fragment start a new intent, however I've implemented it myself

I got it to work now how I wanted but my question to you is - am I using the onListItemClick in the proper way?

here is how i'm using it:

```
public class RandomList extends SherlockListFragment{



    String[] list_contents = {
        "item 1",
        "item 2", 
        "item 3",
        "item 4",
        "item 5"
    };

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, container, false);   
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list_contents));

    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){

        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Object obj = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        String pos = obj.toString();

        if(pos.equals("item 1"))
        {
            Log.i("ListActivity", "found: " + pos);
            //Start an intent....       
        }
        else if(pos.equals("item 2"))
        {
            Log.i("ListActivity", "found: " + pos);
            //Start an intent....
        }
        else if(pos.equals("item 3"))
        {
            Log.i("ListActivity", "found: " + pos);
            //Start an intent....
        }
        else if(pos.equals("item 4"))
        {
            Log.i("ListActivity", "found: " + pos);
            //Start an intent....
        }
        else if(pos.equals("item 5"))
        {
            Log.i("ListActivity", "found: " + pos);
            //Start an intent....
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You're not. Why not switching at 'position' or processing the item at position directly? What are the items and what are your intentions on the items is not clear.

Comment: my intention on the items is to start new classes (with intents)

Comment: >>"public final SherlockListFragment activity = this;" what is this for? Seems like a mistake.

Comment: yes ignore that. I had that in there by mistake when I was testing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok ... really strange question but ... create an Class array like

```
Class[] intentClasses = {1.class,2.class,3.class,4.class,5.class};
```

then in **onListItemClick**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), intentClasses[position]);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: yeah alright, but my question - am I doing something wrong, or does it look ok what I'm doing

Comment: @shellcoder you're doing it wrong. Don't compare anything, just get the class from a list item and process it (as suggested above).

Comment: alright but this class extends a ListFragment so I have to do the intent like                
 
Intent intent = new Intent(this.getActivity(), MainActivity.class);

Comment: @shellcoder So? MainActivity.class should be a list item.

Comment: same , i still cant see whats your problem :)

Comment: yea... but for the first parameter YOURCLASS.this won't work, you have to do getActivity()

Comment: the edit i've suggested will only work (when it extends a ListFragment)

Comment: i know ... its the same ... thats why i typed there YOURCLASS.this :) but ok , if it works please mark answer as correct :P

Comment: That doesn't work when the class extends ListFragment

Comment: @shellcoder it does work if you replace 'this.getActivity()' with 'getActivity()'

Comment: yeah of course... that's not what I'm saying... I'm saying it won't work in this case with whateverclass.this  instead of getActivity() Hope you understand now.

Comment: @shellcoder you should make a Context member (or any other way to make Context accessible) in a class where you need to process onListItemClick().

Comment: yes...contexts.. I'm confused about how to make contexts accessible, I was trying some stuff but didn't get things working right, Have to look into it more